# solving particular integral of $(D^2+1)y=\sin x$..

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was dealing with the particular integral of the differential equation $(D^2+1)y=\sin x$..

$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}y_p&=\frac{\sin x}{D^2+1}\\&=\frac{x\sin x}{2D} \text{since} f(-a^2)=f(-1^2)=0\end{aligned}\end{equation}$

Here I know to take $\frac{1}{D}$ as integral but on what should I apply the integral and why...I mean the next step should be $\frac{1}{2}\int x \sin x $ or $\frac{1}{2}x\int \sin x $....

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It is not fully understandable for me. I know the operator $1/D$ shall follow the whole expression, so it will be $\frac{1}{2}\int x \sin x=\frac12(\sin\,x-x\cos\,x)$ which is indeed the solution.

Comment: How did you get this result:
$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}y_p&=\frac{\sin x}{D^2+1}\\&=\frac{x\sin x}{2D} \text{since} f(-a^2)=f(-1^2)=0\end{aligned}\end{equation}$

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach it's quite easy
The only formula we will need is
$$y=\frac{1}{F(D)}e^{mx}V=e^{mx}\frac{1}{F(D+m)}V$$

Hence $$y_p=\frac{1}{D^2+1}\sin x=\frac{1}{D^2+1}\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$
Now
$$\frac{1}{D^2+1}e^{ix}$$
$$=e^{ix}\frac{1}{(D+i)^2+1} ×1$$
$$=e^{ix}\frac{1}{D(D+2i)}×1$$

$$=e^{ix}\frac{1}{2iD(1+D/2i)}×1$$
$$=e^{ix}\frac{1}{2iD}(1+D/2i)^{-1}×1$$
$$=e^{ix}\frac{1}{2iD}(1-D/2i)×1$$
$$=e^{ix}\frac{1}{2iD}×1$$
$$=e^{ix}\frac{1}{2i}×x$$
Similarly

$$\frac{1}{D^2+1}e^{-ix}$$
$$=e^{-ix}\frac{1}{-2i}×x$$
Hence
$$y_p=\frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix}\frac{1}{2i}×x+e^{-ix}\frac{1}{2i}×x)$$
$$=-\frac{x}{2}(\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2})=-\frac{x}{2}\cos x$$

Comment: I think that in your first line one of the terms should be $F(D+m)$.

Comment: Please kindly explain the step $e^{ix}\frac{1}{2iD}(1+D/2i)^{-1}×1$ is equal to $e^{ix}\frac{1}{2iD}(1-D/2i)×1$ and how can the last operator directly dropped $e^{ix}\frac{1}{2iD}(1-D/2i)×1$?

Comment: @MathArt It's just expanding the form:$$(1+D/2i)^{-1}=1-\frac{D}{2i}+\left(\frac{D}{2i}\right)^2-\left(\frac{D}{2i}\right)^3+•••$$ where $D=\frac{d}{dx}$ .Now $D^n=\frac{d^n}{dx^n}$ and $D^n(1)=\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(1)=0$.. Therefore we get the last operator.

Comment: Very good answer. I honestly learned this for years but still puzzled often.